# How to do some performance testing in asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, performance, asp.net-mvc-2

I am using asp.net mvc 2.0 and I want to test how long it takes to execute some of my code.

In one scenario I do this

1. load xml file up.
2. validate xml file and deserailze.
3. validate all rows in the xml file with more advanced validation that cannot be done in the schema validation.
4. then I do a bulk insert.

I want to measure how long steps 1 to 3 take and how long step 4 takes.

I tried to do like `DateTime.UtcNow` in areas and subtract them but it told me it took like 3 seconds but I know that is not right as steps 1 to 4 take 2mins to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`Stopwatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) class.

```
Stopwatch s = new Stopwatch();
s.Start();
// Run code to be timed
s.Stop();
Debug.Print(s.Elapsed.ToString());
s.Reset();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use Log4Net and save out when you enter the method and when you exit the method.  Plus you could also log at certain points within the method.

Log4Net will give each entry a time code and you can see exactly how long everything is taking.

Comment: I am just looking for something very simple(like the stopwatch). In the future I think I will check this out.